# Why would the dual keel space station design have been more stable?

Tags: iss, gravity, attitude

According to the [space station Freedom wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Station_Freedom#Dual-keel_design_.281986.29) and [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1wncfp/why_does_the_iss_point_the_same_direction/), a dual keel structure would have been more stable than the final ISS design. Can someone explain why?  And if a gravity gradient is the answer, then why is the ISS truss not oriented along the nadir/zenith axis?

Comment: Right in the wikipedia article it says that the dual keel has the advantage of gravity gradient stabilization (they call it "tidal") and of placing the lab module(s) near the center of mass for better microgravity.  I think this explains it pretty well.  The same article says that the original plan was to build the transverse truss first as phase 1 and add the keels later, but the budget was cut.

Comment: I'd advocate for @OrganicMarble's comment to become an answer.